# Необходимо быстро отображать битовую матрицу в WPF

Tags: wpf, графика

Реализую игру Жизнь Конвея, возникла проблема в "быстром отображении"(под быстром понимается каждые 20 милисеунд на форме(или на канвасе) рисовать около 60000 квадратов) матриц каждого хода. Рисую обычным проходом по битовой матрице и "тупой от рисовкой" на канвас(пример метода  ниже), но получается слайд шоу.Есть ли какие-то методы от рисовки больших объемов данных в `WPF`?

```
public static void DrawOnCanvas(bool[,] matrix, Canvas canvas)
{
  int height = matrix.GetLength(0);
  int width = matrix.GetLength(1);
  //размеры матрицы
  for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
    {
      Ellipse eleps = new Ellipse();
      //создаю элипс
      eleps.Height = 4;
      eleps.Width = 4;
      if (matrix[j , i] == true )
      {
          eleps.Fill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
          Canvas.SetLeft(eleps, i * 5);
          Canvas.SetTop(eleps, j * 5);
          canvas.Children.Add(eleps);
          //добавляю его на канвас если в атрице 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Судя по описанию вам может подойти `WriteableBitmap`

Comment: да, именно он и помог

Comment: напишите ответ?

Answer (score 2):

Вот решение данной "проблемы ", я не знаю как считать fps в wpf приложениях но чисто на глаз матрица 256х256 отображается довольно шустро.

```
public static void DrawOnImage(bool[,] outmatrix, Image img)
    {
        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)img.Width,
        (int)img.Height, 1, 1, PixelFormats.Bgra32, null);//создаем типо битмап указывая ширину и высоту формат пиксилей и чето еще вроде как dpi


        Int32Rect rect = new Int32Rect(0, 0, (int)img.Width, (int)img.Height);

        byte[] pixels = new byte[(int)img.Width * (int)img.Height * wb.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8];
        int alpha = 255;
        int red = 0;
        int green = 0;
        int blue = 0;
        int height = outmatrix.GetLength(0);
        int width = outmatrix.GetLength(1);
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++)
            {

                if ((outmatrix[j, i] == true))
                {
                    red = 255;
                }
                else
                {
                    red = 0;
                }
                int pixelOffset = (i + j * wb.PixelWidth) * wb.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8;
                pixels[pixelOffset] = (byte)red;
                pixels[pixelOffset + 1] = (byte)green;
                pixels[pixelOffset + 2] = (byte)blue;
                pixels[pixelOffset + 3] = (byte)alpha;
            }

            int stride = (wb.PixelWidth * wb.Format.BitsPerPixel / 8); //шаги

            wb.WritePixels(rect, pixels, stride, 0);
        }
        img.Source = wb;
    }
```